# Left join in Hive between conversion causing reduction in rows

Tags: sql, hive, impala

hi this is my query in impala. I need to convert this to hive

```
Select count(*)
FROM  ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp as MF
    LEFT JOIN 
          ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp as PDA
            on  PDA.materialnum = MF. materialnum 
            and   MF.loaddate between PDA.FromDate  and PDA.Todate
```

results: 61664421 rows.

my hive version:

```
Select count(*)
FROM  ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp as MF
    LEFT JOIN 
          ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp as PDA
            on  PDA.materialnum = MF. materialnum 
where  (MF.loaddate >= PDA.FromDate   and MF.loaddate <= PDA.Todate)
  or PDA.materialnum is  null
```

results: 59184964 rows.

how can I write this without losing rows?

Comment: Your hive and impala SQL are not same - first one will apply left join on PDA and then count and second one will apply where condition on PDA and then count.So second SQL is more or less act like INNER JOIN. Can you run first SQL in both hive and impala and check?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the filtering condition to the `where` clause:

```
Select count(*)
from ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp MF left join
     ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp PDA
     on PDA.materialnum = MF.materialnum and
        MF.loaddate >= PDA.FromDate and
        MF.loaddate <= PDA.Todate;
```

Oh, that is your first query -- which I assume does not work in Hive due to the inequality in the `on` clause.

There are three possible conditions between the two tables that you are trying to add up:

1. Materials match and the time frames match.
2. Materials match and there are time frames but none match.
3. No material matches.

Your second query is only getting (1) and (3).  The second is rather tricky, given the limitations of not having the flexibility of the `on` clause.  You can calculate it using:

```
select count(*)
from (select count(*)
      from ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp MF join
           ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp PDA
           on PDA.materialnum = MF.materialnum
      group by MF.materialnum
      having sum(case when MF.loaddate >= PDA.FromDate and MF.loaddate <= PDA.Todate then 1 else 0 end) = 0
     ) MF;
```

And although I don't think this will work in Hive, an alternative formulation is:

```
select count(*)
from ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp MF
where not exists (select 1
                  from ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp PDA
                  where PDA.materialnum = MF.materialnum and
                        MF.loaddate >= PDA.FromDate and MF.loaddate <= PDA.Todate
                 );
```

These give you the difference which you can add back in.

Comment: I should have wrote that I don't really need the count. I look  at the count to find out why am i getting diffrent data at the end.
what I really need :
Select MF.*, PDA.mmpp
FROM  ud_planning.WIM_MF2_Temp as MF
    LEFT JOIN 
          ud_planning.WIM_PDA_Temp as PDA
            on  PDA.materialnum = MF. materialnum 
            and   MF.loaddate between PDA.FromDate  and PDA.Todate ;

Comment: my first query does not include case where materials match and there are time frames but none match.

Comment: @אלהעיןגדי . . . The query in the question handles that case.